# Utilizar git em hospedagem hostgator em ssh por meio de chave púplico/privada

Tags: git, ssh

Estou tentando acessar minha hospedagem através do sistema de chave pública e privada mas ta dando erro quando crio o arquivo config pra acessa-lo sem senha

Eu criei a chave no gitbash através do comando "ssh-keygen" e copiei/colei na área do cpanel para importar uma chave publica e autorizei a mesma; criei o arquivo config com nessa estrutura:

Host rafael

HostName -ip da minha hospedagem-

Port 2222

User -usuário q uso pra acessar o cpanel-

mas quando tento acessar por meio de "ssh rafael" da erro "ssh: Could not resolve hostname rafael: Name or service not known". Lembrando logar com usuário e senha que entro no cpanel mas por questão de fluxo de trabalho quero fazer desse jeito. Alguém tem alguma luz sobre o que eu possa estar errando?

Comment: Você deveria usar o comando `ssh rafael@ip -p2222`, algo assim. Usuário @ servidor

Comment: eu coloco essa sintaxe, ele pede uma senha sendo que eu configurei a chave sem senha... e dá o mesmo erro :/

Answer (score -2):

Acho que isto pode te ajudar.

Não é da hostgator, mas é o mesmo princípio.
https://wiki.teltonika-networks.com/view/SSH_RSA_key_authentication_(Linux)